# Defining ValueList Annotation for mapping entity sets of an OData project

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am developing an SAPUI5 app using Smart Table and Smart Filter. I have added local annotations for LineItem and SelectionFields for this purpose in my Web IDE project. The table is being rendered as expected, but not the Smart Filter. I am not able to get suggestions and value help for my input filter since there are no OData annotations for this.

Is it possible to add ValueList annotation in the Local Annotations file in the Web IDE project to map the main entity set and the value help entity set? The required entity set that I want for the value help is already a part of the OData service. But, I was unable to find ValueList annotation under Common Vocabulary in the annotation modeler. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, create second entity with dictionary and add in local annotation file valuelist annotation.